# Different public IP when connect my mobile with my VPN server

Tags: vpn, openvpn

When I connect my mobile to my VPN server gives me other IP public. Do you know how could I preserve the same public IP that my lan of my VPN server?
Note

VPN is done in my lan in a computer with Windows 7 with openvpn

Thanks

Comment: Edit this question to include more details about the VPN server - is it something you run, your work runs, something you pay for, etc.

Comment: What VPN are you using?

Comment: Vpn is done in my lan in a computer with Windows 7 with openvpn

Comment: Your question does not make any sense.  what does "other IP public" mean?  Are you certain that when you connect via your mobile the traffic is going through your VPN - I posit that this is not happening which is why the reported IP address is different (although I can hypothesize other possibilities)

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear.  It's OK if English is not your native language, but in order for people to help you are going to have to explain yourself.